How can I return the employee type based on a field on the User record?
As I need to create a formula field in "Interaction" object with the following condition:
If the length of BXTRE_CostCenter__c is greater than 4 and it begins with '7' then this employee is a Vantive person. Otherwise the employee is Baxter.
Please note that BXTRE_CostCenter__c is the field from "User" object.
Additional details for this formula:
1.The formula field label to be created is "Company"
2. For Interaction Owners linked to cost centers starting with 7 with more than 4 digits, default Company to “Vantive”
3.For Interaction Owners all other cost centers, default Company to “Baxter”
My attempt from all the suggestions:
IF(
NOT(ISBLANK($Owner)),
AND(
LEN($User.BXTRE_CostCenter__c) > 4,
BEGINS($User.BXTRE_CostCenter__c, "7")
),
"Vantive",
"Baxter"
)
But receiving the error: Error: Field $Owner does not exist. Check spelling
So, can someone please help me in solving this?
Thanks,
Rudraswamy

You should include the attempt that you've made so far.

Hi @DerekF, Please find my attempt for the formula field creation:

IF(
NOT(ISBLANK($Owner)),
AND(
LEN($User.BXTRE_CostCenter__c) > 4,
BEGINS($User.BXTRE_CostCenter__c, "7")
),
"Vantive",
"Baxter"
)

Receiving this error: Error: Field $Owner does not exist. Check spelling. as i tried to modify as per suggestion of @Renato Oliveira

you should [edit] your question to include details like that.

@DerekF, I have now edited my question. Please do find the additional details. Thanks

@Rudraswamy, I have updated my answer.

There is no "Owner" field in "User" object, we need to create formula field for "Interaction" object record Owners @TusharJadav

@Rudraswamy, The Owner field of the Interaction object is the relationship with the User object.

The below formula checks the length of the BXTRE_CostCenter__c field from the "User" object and determines if the employee is a Vantive person or a Baxter employee:
IF(
    AND(
        LEN($User.BXTRE_CostCenter__c) > 4,
        BEGINS($User.BXTRE_CostCenter__c, "7")
    ),
    "Vantive",
    "Baxter"
)

Update(21/08/2024):
If you refer to the owner field then the formula will be as follows:
IF(
    AND(
        LEN(Owner.BXTRE_CostCenter__c) > 4,
        BEGINS(Owner.BXTRE_CostCenter__c, "7")
    ),
    "Vantive",
    "Baxter"
)

Update(22/08/2024):
The error is because the Owner field is a polymorphic field that can reference either a User or a Group. To resolve this, you need to specify the object type for the Owner field in your formula.
IF(
        AND(
                ISBLANK(Owner:User.BXTRE_CostCenter__c) = FALSE,
                LEN(Owner:User.BXTRE_CostCenter__c) > 4,
                BEGINS(Owner:User.BXTRE_CostCenter__c, "7")
        ),
        "Vantive",
        "Baxter"
)


Thank you so much and here we have to use $User.BXTRE_CostCenter__c @Tushar Jadav

@Rudraswamy, I have updated the formula as per your comment. Please check.

Error: Field $OwnerBXTRE_CostCenter__c does not exist. Check spelling. @Tushar Jadav

@Rudraswamy, You do not need to add $ sign before the Owner. Just add Owner.BXTRE_CostCenter__c

Okay, I have added now Owner.BXTRE_CostCenter__c, but receiving the Error: Specify an object type for the Owner field.  @Tushar Jadav

@Rudraswamy, BXTRE_CostCenter__c this field is on User Object?

Yes, BXTRE_CostCenter__c is from User object. I need to create this formula field in "Interaction" object @Tushar Jadhav

@Rudraswamy, So in the Interaction object there is a field called Owner. The Owner field is Lookup(User, Group). So you can refer to the User object custom field in the Interaction formula field.  Have you tried the formula that I have added in my answer in update section?

Yes, i have tried the formula which you have added in Update section, but still receiving Error: Specify an object type for the Owner field. @Tushar Jadhav

@Rudraswamy, Check my Update(22/08/2024) section in answer for this error.

Thanks a lot for providing detailed information in Update(22/08/2024) section and resolving this. @Tushar Jadav

@Rudraswamy, Upvote the answer if you have found this helpful.

That depends on which user you are referring to. While the formula posted by Tushar is correct on his answer, you didn't specify whether you are referring to the current user viewing the record, or if you are referring to a lookup on the interaction record that looks up to a user record.
That field could be the record owner, its creator or the person who last modified the record. Either way, that field is what you'll need to reference in the formula with Owner., CreatedBy. or LastModified..

Owner.BXTRE_CostCenter__c
CreatedBy.BXTRE_CostCenter__c
LastModifiedBy.BXTRE_CostCenter__c
CustomReference__r.BXTRE_CostCenter__c - in this case, you'll also want to check if the field is null in your formula, as below:

IF(
    NOT(ISBLANK(CustomReference__c)),
    AND(
        LEN(CustomReference__r.BXTRE_CostCenter__c) > 4,
        BEGINS(CustomReference__r.BXTRE_CostCenter__c, "7")
    ),
    "Vantive",
    "Baxter"
)


So, may i please know what will be the "CustomReference" here for "Interaction Record Owner"?
